# TypeError: he_uniform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I want to conduct the file which is beam training, the error took place.
There is my original code.

```
(python37) F:\pythonProject>python beam_train_model.py --lidar_training_data
2023-03-29 16:00:44.660104: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2023-03-29 16:00:44.660248: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beam_train_model.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models import Lidar2D
  File "F:\pythonProject\models.py", line 27, in <module>
    layers.Softmax()
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 213, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 897, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2416, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 163, in build
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2598, in default_variable_creator
    shape=shape)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 263, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1434, in __init__
    distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1567, in _init_from_args
    initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py", line 121, in <lambda>
    init_val = lambda: initializer(shape, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: he_uniform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

Help me solve this. I try to update gym and change (dtype = dtype) to (dtype = None)

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: he_uniform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

This means there is no the argument `dtype` in the function `he_uniform()`. Therefore, even if you change the value `dtype = dtype` -> `dtype = None`, this is not applicable. You have to deliver the argument without describing `dtype`.

For instance,

```
he_uniform(dtype = None) -> he_uniform()
```

Comment: I ask the BingAi and update my tensorflow version from 2.2.0 to 2.3.0 and the problem is solved. Thank you!